# How to swap Left Shift and Left Alt key on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: keyboard-layout, remapping

I added the following code at the end of `xkb_symbols pc105` of the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`

```
replace key <LALT> { [ Shift_L ] };
replace key <LFSH> { [ Alt_L ] };
```

It worked as expected. But after a recent system update, the remapping of Left <kbd>Shift</kbd> Key to the Left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key failed. The Left <kbd>Shift</kbd> is now still the Left <kbd>Shift</kbd>. Any idea of how to fix this issue?